# In how many ways can $6$ boys and $6$ girls be seated at $3$ groups of four desks if there are two adjacent boys and two adjacent girls in each group?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So the problem is,

There is a class of 12 students, 6 boys and 6 girls. There are 3 clusters of desks in a room. Each cluster consists of 2 boys sat next to each other and 2 girls sat next to each other. What is the total number of ways the students can be arranged.

This is what I have tried so far but not sure if I am right by using combinations:
$$\dfrac{\left({6 \choose 2}\times{6 \choose2} \right)^3}{12!}$$
$$=\dfrac{225^3}{479001600}$$

I have drawn a picture of the problem to clarify.

[image: picture]

Comment: are we selecting them some way ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strategy:**

1. Choose which two of the six boys and which two of the six girls sit at the cluster of four desks closest to Mr. Zerk.
2. Choose on which side of that cluster of desks the boys sit.
3. Arrange the two selected boys on that side.
4. Arrange the two selected girls on the other side.
5. Choose which two of the four remaining boys and which two of the four remaining girls sit at the cluster of four desks closest to the sliding door.
6. Choose on which side of that cluster of desks the boys sit.
7. Arrange the two selected boys on that side.
8. Arrange the two selected girls on the other side.
9. Choose on which side of the remaining cluster of four desks the remaining two boys will sit.
10. Arrange those boys on that side.
11. Arrange the two remaining girls on the other side.
12. Apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

> $$\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{2}{1}2!2!\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}2!2!\binom{2}{1}2!2!$$

Comment: We have to show we used a formula should i use combinations or permutations?

Comment: You use combinations to select a subset and permutations when you make an arrangement.  Step 1:  $\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2}$.  Step 2: $\binom{2}{1}$.  Step 3: $2!$.  Step 4: $2!$.  Can you continue?

Comment: Bit confused is there a simple formula I could use to work out the total possible ways you rearrange students using permutation or combinations?

Comment: Step 1: Two of the six boys are selected in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways and two of the six girls are selected in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways.  Since these choices are independent, we multiply to obtain $\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select two of the six boys and two of the six girls.  Step 2: We choose one of the two sides in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways.  Step 3: We arrange the two boys in $2!$ ways.  Step 4:  We arrange the two girls in $2!$ ways.  There is not a simple formula.  However, if you understand the first four steps, you should be able to apply similar reasoning to the remaining steps.

Comment: Something like this? https://imgur.com/gwF4IRb

Comment: What you have counted is the number of ways of selecting which students are placed at which cluster of desks.  You still need to arrange them.  I have added an answer.  See if it makes sense.  If you have more questions, please ask.

Comment: With your equation are you using permutations or combinations? Also is the (2/1) needed if the boys can only stay on one side and not switch sides with the girls?

Comment: I use combinations whenever I choose a subset and permutations whenever I am arranging people.  The notation $\binom{n}{k}$ represents the number of ways of choosing a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements.  For instance, we initially select $2$ of the $6$ boys to sit at the table closest to Mr. Zerk.  The factor $\binom{2}{1}$ represents the number of ways we can choose a side of the cluster for the boys.  If there was only one side on which the boys could sit, we would not need that factor.  The factor $2!$ represents the number of ways we could arrange the boys on their side.

Comment: The number of combinations is given by the formula $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$  The number $n!$ represents the number of ways of permuting $n$ objects.  Note that step 1 contributes the factor $\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2}$ since we are selecting both two of the six boys and two of the six girls.  Similarly, tep 5 contributes the factor $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ since we are selecting two of the remaining four boys and two of the remaining four girls.  With that in mind, compare the factors in the answer with the steps I outlined in the strategy to see how I obtained the answer.

Comment: Last question hopefully you have been amazing so far, so did you use permutations when selecting 2 of the six boys and 2 of the six girls and so on. And combinations when choosing a side for the boys. And also do the boys always sit next to each other when switching sides in your equations?

Comment: I used combinations when selecting the boys (since we are selecting a subset of boys), combinations when selecting the girls, combinations when selecting the side for the boys (since we are selecting one of the two sides of each cluster of desks), permutations when arranging the boys, and permutations when arranging the girls.  The boys do always sit on the same side of the cluster, the one we have selected for the boys.